# Django and Postgis: How can I create a spatial table with CONSTRAINT enforce_geotype_geom in Django?

Tags: django, postgresql, postgis, psql

I'm trying to create a spatial table like this([from here](http://www.kevfoo.com/2012/01/Importing-CSV-to-PostGIS/)):

```
CREATE TABLE landmarks
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  name character varying(50),
  the_geom geometry,
  CONSTRAINT landmarks_pkey PRIMARY KEY (gid),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_dims_the_geom CHECK (st_ndims(the_geom) = 2),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_geotype_geom CHECK (geometrytype(the_geom) = 'POINT'::text OR the_geom IS NULL),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_srid_the_geom CHECK (st_srid(the_geom) = 4326)
);
```

How can I create a table like this in Django model? I know how to create the fields but dont know how to add the `CONSTRAINT`.

Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The old PostGIS model before 2.x used constraints like in the question. The newer style uses typmods like `geometry(Point, 4326)`.

The old style can set up manually using the appropriate DDL, or with the utility function [AddGeometryColumn](http://postgis.org/docs/AddGeometryColumn.html) with `use_typmod=false`.

The newer typmod style is typically recommended over the older constraints-based style.